# ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10 seems to be related to ForeignKey

Tags: django, django-models

Trying to get to the bottom of this error. Several SO questions on the subject and the answers range from: deleting previous migrations, setting default value in the model for the field, or using a `GenericForeignKey`. None have resolved my issue thus far.

I am fairly certain the issue is related to `ForeignKey` and have read it uses `int()` by default even if the field is `CharField`.

Here is the field in question in the model I am trying use:

```
product_code = models.ForeignKey(Products, null=False)
```

Here is the field in the parent model it is referring to (`Products`):

```
code = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=16)
```

And here is the query where the issue is occurring:

```
# returns 'A_17'
product_code = Products.objects.get(id=data['product_id']).code

# error triggered here:
print(ProductPositions.objects.filter(product_code=product_code))

# ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'A_17'
```

So it appears to be string from end-to-end, but I guess with the `ForeignKey` "defaulting" to integer or something the issue is related to that. Not sure how to override that as something like `default=''` doesn't work.

Not sure how to clear up the issue so thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the actually code to do the lookup and it is anticipating the primary key. You can alter this two ways
Using the primary key:

```
product_code = Products.objects.get(id=data['product_id'])
print(ProductPositions.objects.filter(product_code=product_code.pk))
```

Or using the code (the `__` will tell Django to refer the field through the foreign key):

```
product_code = Products.objects.get(id=data['product_id']).code
print(ProductPositions.objects.filter(product_code__code=product_code))
```

Comment: NOTE: Stuart's answer did answer the question I had and it made this particular error go away. However, other errors came up which finally lead to an issue with the how I had the model put together. That solution is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48348266/3123109