# "Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: X_XX"

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-models, mariadb

Django's ORM just isn't clicking for me, but I intend to spend the weekend reading through the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/) in order to make it click.

Meanwhile, I have an issue I need to resolve that I haven't been able to.

The first I had was here, which was resolved with the answer provided:

[ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10 seems to be related to ForeignKey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48332604/valueerror-invalid-literal-for-int-with-base-10-seems-to-be-related-to-foreig)

I have modified my query to:

```
# data['product_id] = 78
# returns A_17
product_code = Products.objects.get(id=data['product_id']).code

# this is where the error occurs
print(ProductPositions.objects.filter(product_code__code=product_code))
```

> /mnt/c/dev/current/client/.venv/client/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymysql/cursors.py:166: Warning: (1292, "Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: 'A_15'")
>
> result = self._query(query)

I am not even sure why it is looking at `A_15` because it should only be filtering on `A_17`, so that is one issue I don't understand

To explain these tables because I don't think it is really intuitive. The `Products` will look something like this (with columns not relevant to this removed):

```
-- Products table
id     code
--------------
77     A_16
78     A_17
81     M_15
```

There are multiple of the `code` in the `ProductPositions`. `code` is more like a line of products and and `product_no` (which I haven't got to yet and is the next step) are the products in that line. Ultimately, I am trying to get the description, but only at the point of filtering `A_17` currently. So it will look like:

```
-- ProductPositions table
product_code         product_no       description
-------------------------------------------------
A_17                 ABC123           Widget 1
A_17                 DEF456           Widget 2
A_17                 GHI789           Widget 3
A_16                 ABC123           Widget 1
A_16                 DEF456           Widget 2
A_16                 GHI789           Widget 3
```

These are the models for each:

```
class Products(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    code = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=16)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    short_name = models.CharField(max_length=128)

class ProductPositions(models.Model):
    product_code = models.ForeignKey(Products, db_column='product_code', null=False)
    product_no = models.DecimalField(unique=True, max_digits=12, decimal_places=1, primary_key=True)
    product_title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    product_description = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.product_description

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'Product_Positions'
        unique_together = ('product_code', 'product_no')
```

Also, it seems like it might be an error generated by the database. However, when I do the following in `./manage.py shell` to see a list of raw SQL queries, nothing comes up (only one connection and it isn't named):

```
>>> from django.db import connection
>>> connection.queries
[]
```

Anyway, ultimately trying to get to `ProductPositions.objects.filter(product_code__code=product_code).filter(product_no=data['product_no'].description`, but running into issues every step of the way.

**And to be clear on the issue: a string is being passed to `varchar` field, but the error is coming back with `double`. Why?**

Comment: "A_17" is not numeric, it is a string.  You can't get a DOUBLE from it.

Comment: Exactly. `product_code = 'A_17'` and the field it is being used as a filter parameter for is obviously a string as well, so what is this `DOUBLE` business about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, finally figured out what the issue was after turning verbose debugging on such that I could actually see the queries being sent. The issue was how it was being joined and it was using the `pk` of `Products` by default.

```
ProductPositions.objects.filter(product_code__code=product_c‌​ode)
```

Was basically being translated into:

```
... INNER JOIN.... ON 'ProductPositions'.'product_code' = 'Products'.'id'
```

Which I really did not want. It should have been:

```
... INNER JOIN.... ON 'ProductPositions'.'product_code' = 'Products'.'code'
```

So the solution was to fix the `product_code` field in the `ProductPositions` model by adding `to_field`. As the documentation says:

> For fields like ForeignKey that map to model instances, defaults should be the value of the field they reference (pk unless to_field is set) instead of model instances.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.to_field

```
product_code = models.ForeignKey(Products, to_field='code', db_column='product_code', null=False)
```

Now data is retrieving as expected and without errors.

Answer (score 0):

your query contain a typo mistake at the end

```
object = ProductPositions.objects.filter(product_code__code=product_code,
                                product_no=data['product_no'])
print(object.product_description)
```

**Warning: (1292, "Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: 'A_15'")** is because of you are comparing two incompatible data type in your query I guess.

assuming A_15 is stored in the first row of the table it is raising an error. Make sure you are passing the value of **data['product_no']** as per field constraints i.e including decimal value.

let me know if this help.

PS: posting this as an answer because I don't have enough point to comment.

**EDIT:**

Assuming that you are passing the correct values for **product_code** and **product_no** you can get the correct instance as

```
obj = get_object_or_404(ProductPositions,
                        product_code__code=product_code,
                        product_no=data['product_no'])
print(obj.product_description)
```

This is working for me.
[image]

Comment: `product_no` and `data['product_no']` are both `DOUBLE`. That being said the bit of the query that is causing the error is the `ProductPositions.objects.filter(product_code__code=product_code)`.

Comment: see updated answer, if you are still unable to resolve it, I request you to post complete traceback and views function that you are using to pass values.